# Does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS work with only 736MB of RAM?

Tags: performance

I want to install it on my old desktop PC. here is it's specs:

- CPU: Intel Pentium 4@2.4GHz
- RAM: 736 MB
- VRAM: 256MB
- HDD: 120GB

I can install the following OSes on it:

- Windows Vista Home Basic w/SP2
- Mac OS X v.10.5.8 "Leopard"
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: [Here is the System Requirements page for Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install 32bit version of it. But probably it will be really slow.Installing 12.04 would be a little bit better for you.

Comment: It'll be great. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is really bad for slow computers. I can't use it on 2GB RAM and new processor.